# Error in GTM: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: const declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, utm

I am trying to parse UTMs and get them into fields but it seems that my script won't publish on GTM.

(the script works when directly put on webflow custom code)

````
  var queryString = window.location.search;
  console.log(queryString);
  // ?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=webflow
  var URLSearchParams_wb = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

  const utmParameters = [
    "utm_campaign", 
    "utm_source", 
    "utm_medium",
    "utm_content",
    "utm_term"
  ];

  for (const utm_element of utmParameters) {
    /* if utm_source exist */
    if(URLSearchParams_wb.has(utm_element)){
      console.log(utm_element + " : is exist");
      /* get UTM value of this utm param */
      var value = URLSearchParams_wb.get(utm_element)
      /* change form hidden feild to this utm url value */
      $("."+utm_element).val(value);
    }
  }/* end for loop */
</script>```

Any idea ?
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GTM has troubles adopting ES6.
Therefore:

1. Get rid of consts. Use vars instead.
2. That jquery piece. better get rid of it too. You don't need a dependency on jquery living in GTM. But it doesn't break the code.
3. Your for of construction is from es6 too, I believe: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ so the loop will likely have to be rewritten to something different. I would just use forEach rather than that for of.

The rest should be good. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ECMA6/ECMA5 converter such as https://jstool.gitlab.io/babel-es6-to-es5/